# WPF TabItem Style with image

Tags: wpf, styles, tabcontrol, tabitem, contentpresenter

I have a `TabControl` with `TabItem`s, The `TabItem`s have text and an icon. To do this I have to add a `StackPanel` to the `TabItem`.

However, once I add the `StackPanel`, I can no longer control the default style of the text.

Resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid Name="tabItem">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Name="tabItemStyle" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0, 0, 5, 0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" TextBlock.Foreground="White" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="14,3,18,3">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="Background" Value="#ecf3f9" />
                        <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#29458e" />
                        <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#29458e" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="Background" Value="#6381be" />
                            <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#97acd4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="tabItemStyle" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

TabItem:

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/images/icons/_24/reports.png" Width="24" />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0" >Reports</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

The relevant line is the `ContentPresenter` in the Resource (Style). The `TextBlock.Foreground="White"` no longer works. I can see why but cannot find out how else to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: you could just colour the text in the textblock definition

Comment: All of the tabs have the same color schemes. The foreground color has to be changed in the trigger. Otherwise I would be duplicating a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the relevant properties on the actual `TabItem`. For instance, notice if you put the following at the top of the style:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
```

the text still changes. You don't need to refer to the `ContentPresenter`'s `TextBlock`, and even if you did, you could apply [`TemplateBindings`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/599954/WPF-TemplateBinding-with-ControlTemplate) to its properties so that when `TabItem`'s properties changed, so did `ContentPresenter`'s.